# Do I need to cite this information?

Tags: citations

In an introduction to my paper I have given a basic introduction to Machine learning and how an investigation is conducted.
None of the information is really specific to any source - it’s basically an account of the basic terms, ideas and processes used by anyone doing a machine learning investigation.

Comment: Does https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/159078/63475 help answer your question?

Comment: @BryanKrause It helps somewhat. Even though it’s a basic introduction (talks about neural networks, basic training idea, data splitting, feature selection and assessing network performance in about 2 pages) I still thought to include it as it was a summer project and I was new to the topic.

Comment: Yeah, citation norms (and relevant information) vary quite a bit between research papers to be published for the public, and papers you are writing for a class project. If the latter, what matters most is your instructor's expectations, which we can guess at but not know, only your instructor will know for sure.

Comment: @BryanKrause I intend to upload it to arXiv if that makes a difference?

Comment: Then personally I'd go with what I wrote in the answer to the linked question: *Either you refer to things "common knowledge" - in that case, really not much need to cite but also no reason to put in your paper as its own section, or you refer to things "not common knowledge" and you provide citations.*

Answer (score 1):

In these circumstances, I *rarely* rely on the notion that something is "common knowledge" unless it really is ***so well known*** as to be, as legal writers describe it, "notorious" (e.g., the fact that Wednesday follows Tuesday). It is easy for academic writers to forget what it is like to be ignorant (not stupid ... just ignorant of certain facts) and it is of very low cost to insert a parenthetical statement (or footnote) that says, "For a brief introduction to the main concepts of XXX, see for example, Smith and Jones, 1988; a more detailed exposition can be found in Desert & Waste, 2024)".

The reader who doesn't need the reference will just skip over it; others will be immensely grateful. If your audience is the body of your peers, or a class tutor, it will still not go amiss.